# ajax url directs me to .php?userid=undefined

Tags: javascript

When I click on the button, it redirects me to removeadmin.php?userid=undefined . My intended result was eg removeadmin.php?userid=0001 depending on which button the person has pressed. I have tried to change to window.location = "removeadmin.php?userid=" + arr[i].userid However, nothing seems to work.

```
(function () {
$(document).ready(function () {
showadmin();
});

function showadmin() {
var url = serverURL() + "/showadmin.php";

var userid = "userid";
var employeename = "employeename";
var role ="role";

var JSONObject = {
"userid": userid,
"employeename": employeename,
"role": role
 };

 var myJSON = JSON.stringify(JSONObject);

$.ajax({
url: url,
type: 'POST',
data: JSONObject,
dataType: 'json',
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
success: function (arr) {
_getAdminResult(arr);
},
error: function () {
        alert("fail");
}
});
}

 function _getAdminResult(arr) {
var gridcontainers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var gridcontainer = $("<div />").addClass("grid-container");
    gridcontainer.append($("<div />").text(arr[i].userid));
    gridcontainer.append($("<div />").text(arr[i].employeename));
    gridcontainer.append($("<div />").text(arr[i].role));
    gridcontainer.append($("<div />").append(
        $("<button />")
            .on("click", BtnRemoveAdmin)
            .text("Remove")
    ));
    gridcontainers.push(gridcontainer);
    }
$("#name").append(gridcontainers);
 }      

 function BtnRemoveAdmin(event) {
var data = event.data;
removeadmin(event.data);
 }


 function removeadmin(userid) {
  window.location = "removeadmin.php?userid=" + userid;
 }


 })();
```

Comment: What is arr value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply `event.data` is undefined. Change `_getAdminResult` and `BtnRemoveAdmin` functions with this

```
function _getAdminResult(arr) {
var gridcontainers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var gridcontainer = $("<div />").addClass("grid-container");
    gridcontainer.append($("<div />").text(arr[i].userid));
    gridcontainer.append($("<div />").text(arr[i].employeename));
    gridcontainer.append($("<div />").text(arr[i].role));
    gridcontainer.append($("<div />").append(
        $("<button />")
            .on("click", BtnRemoveAdmin)
            .attr("data-userid", arr[i].userid) 
            .text("Remove")
    ));
    gridcontainers.push(gridcontainer);
    }
$("#name").append(gridcontainers);
 }      

 function BtnRemoveAdmin() {
var data = $(this).attr("data-userid");
removeadmin(data);
 }
```